# ejb3: mapping many-to-many relationship jointable with a simple primary key

Tags: java, orm, jpa, mapping, many-to-many

often in books, i see that when a many-to-many relationship is translated to a DB schema, the JoinTable gets a compound key consisting of the primary keys of the tables involved in many-to-many relationship.
I try to avoid compound keys completely. So i usually create a surrogate key even for the JoinTable and allow the database to fill it up by trigger or whatever feature a database has for incrementing primary keys. It just seems like a much simpler approach.

the only issue i can think is that, there are chances of duplication of foreign key pair in the JoinTable. But this can be avoided by a simple query before a row is inserted in the JoinTable.

Since books always use the compound keys approach, i wanted to know if, there are any negative effects if i use simple one column surrogate keys for the JoinTable?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, using a single primary key is a bad idea.

First, as you said, a single primary key won't ensure unicity in the database. Sure, you can check this at runtime using a simple query, but this is costly, and if you forget just one time to do your check query, you can put your database in an inconsistent state.

Also, I think that using an additional column for the primary key is, in this case, not necessary. You don't need to identify relationships by a unique primary key, since the relationship is already defined by two unique keys: the primary keys of your two tables. In this case, you'll have unnecessary data, that will add complexity to your data model, and that you'll probably never use.

Comment: the query isn't that costly.., it only searches the related rows . But yes, forgetting it would be a problem. Thanks, i guess your argument provide a solid advantage for using the compound keys. Also i found a related article here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870/one-or-two-primary-keys-in-many-to-many-table

Answer (score 1):

> I try to avoid compound keys completely.

Huh? Why? I mean, why *totally* avoiding them? What's the reason behind this?

> So i usually create a surrogate key even for the JoinTable and allow the database to fill it up by trigger or whatever feature a database has for incrementing primary keys. It just seems like a much simpler approach.

No offense but we don't have the same definition of simplicity then. I really don't see where it is simpler.

> The only issue i can think is that, there are chances of duplication of foreign key pair in the JoinTable. But this can be avoided by a simple query before a row is inserted in the JoinTable.

First of all, don't use a SELECT to check uniqueness (you can have a race condition, a SELECT without locking the whole table won't guarantee anything), use a UNIQUE constraint, that's what UNIQUE is for.

And lets imagine one second that a SELECT would have been possible, do you really find that  simpler? In general, people try to avoid hitting the database if possible. They also avoid having to do extra work.

> Since books always use the compound keys approach, i wanted to know if, there are any negative effects if i use simple one column surrogate keys for the JoinTable?

So you mean something like this:

```
   A              A_B                 B
-------      ------------------    --------
ID (PK)      ID (PK),              ID (PK)
             A_ID (FK),
             B_ID (FK),
             UNIQUE(A_ID, B_ID)
```

Sure, you could do that (and you could even map it with JPA if you use some kind of trigger or identity column for the ID). But I don't see the point:

1. The above design is just not the standard way to map a (m:n) relation, it's not what people are used to find.
2. A_B is not really an Entity by itself (which is what the model somehow suggests, see #1).

   - The couple (A_ID, B_ID) is a natural candidate for the key, why not using it (and wasting space)?
   - The above design is **not** simpler, it does introduce more complexity.

To sum up, I don't see any advantage.