# SchemeExport and creating of primary key for many-to-many table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I use SchemeExport to create database scheme. Many-to-many tables creates without primary key (only two foreign keys). Is it possible to create primary key too?

Comment: Why do you need a primary key on a many-to-many table?

Comment: Why not? I can add two (or more) identical rows without primary key and searching operations will be slower. I think each table must have primary key. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've found question about it http://stackoverflow.com/q/38870/511041. I have option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post something more about your domain?
To create a surrogate key on many-to-many associations is hardly a good choice and there may be a more appropriate domain modeling.

If you are concerned about performance, do some comparative tests with indexes or [unique constraint on both FK columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463499/how-to-create-composite-unique-constraint-in-fluentnhibernate/480964#480964).
I'm pretty sure that create a surrogate Id is going to result on poor insert performance and will not improve search performance as searchs are almost always based on both FK columns.